# What privilege's do need to create Azure Active Directory App?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

My Azure account is under company's AD, and once i tried to create an App using Azure Devops, when trying to create New Service connection, this error pops up,

[image]

What permission do my account needs to perform this action ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need the "Creator" permission:

> Members of this role can create the service connection in the project. Contributors are added as members by default

Please find more information in the Microsoft documentation [User permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#user-permissions)

Microsoft documentation for [Manage service connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#prerequisites)

Comment: The problem lies in not having privileges to create app registrations in the Azure Active Directory tenant

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in not having privileges to create app registrations in the Azure Active Directory tenant. There are several roles that have permission for this operation. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#permissions-required-for-registering-an-app) it also depends on whether non-admin users can create app registrations.

Some [Built-in roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#all-roles) that can be used are [Application Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#application-administrator)

> Users in this role can create and manage all aspects of enterprise applications, application registrations, and application proxy settings. Note that users assigned to this role are not added as owners when creating new application registrations or enterprise applications.

or [Application Developer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#application-developer)

> Users in this role can create application registrations when the "Users can register applications" setting is set to No. This role also grants permission to consent on one's own behalf when the "Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf" setting is set to No. Users assigned to this role are added as owners when creating new application registrations.